# How to Change Default Number of Posts Showing in a Blog in Enfold Theme for Wordpress

Tags: blogs, archive, wordpress

m working on wordpress with enfold theme, 
http://themeforest.net/item/enfold-responsive-multipurpose-theme/4519990

here enfold showing 10 posts on a archive/Category page by default , i want to change to it and wanna make it to 9 posts by defaults

so if anybody can suggest i can got the solution

Regards
Surinder Singh

Comment: This is premium theme no one has access to. You should contact themeforest's support for help on this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the admin, have you try to go to `Settings > Reading` and change the default amount ? And in the theme options ?

If it has no effect, we can't really give you a precise answer because the source code for this theme is not accessible.

If you know some PHP, you can:

- find in the theme the file where the number of posts in archive/category page is defined
- create a [Child Theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)
- copy the file to your child theme and change the value

Comment: Thanks Eliot Berriot, its so easy solution, how can i skip that :)
anyway Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, follow the red marks :)

[image]